# Trouble selecting option in display: none dropdown Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I dont ask this question lightly, but it proving to be more problematic than I thought.  I have trawled through google looking at possible solutions but it seems I just cannot select a specific option from a dropdown list.

If anyone can give me a pointer or a solution it would be very welcome as I am pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="main-content" class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
    <div
        class="form-horizontal col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>Please sign in</h1>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible:loginExternal"
                            style="display: none;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 100%;"
                                    unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns=""
                                    aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
                                    <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"
                                    unselectable="on"> <span class="k-input"
                                        unselectable="on">Please select ...</span> <span
                                        class="k-select" unselectable="on"> <span
                                            class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
                                    </span>
                                </span> <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="display"
                                    data-option-label="Please select ..."
                                    style="width: 100%; display: none;"
                                    data-value-primitive="true" data-value-field="irn"
                                    data-bind="source: locations, value: selectedLocation">
                                        <option value="822">Alexandra</option>
                                        <option value="800">Ridge</option>
                                        <option value="896">Ture</option>
                                        <option value="899">Grove</option>
                                        <option value="824">Lea</option>
                                        <option value="825">Mount</option>
                                        <option value="894">Cliffe</option>
                                        <option value="788">Bank</option>
                                        <option value="826">Ponga</option>
                                        <option value="259">Post</option>
                                </select>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 100%;"
                                    unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="loginSubLoc_listbox"
                                    aria-disabled="true" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false"
                                    aria-activedescendant="loginSubLoc_option_selected"> <span
                                    class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-disabled" unselectable="on">
                                        <span class="k-input" unselectable="on"></span> <span
                                        class="k-select" unselectable="on"> <span
                                            class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
                                    </span>
                                </span> <select id="loginSubLoc" data-role="dropdownlist"
                                    data-text-field="display"
                                    data-option-label="Please select ..."
                                    style="width: 100%; display: none;"
                                    data-value-primitive="true" data-value-field="irn"
                                    data-bind="source: sublocations, value: selectedsubLocation, enabled: isSublocationEnabled"
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                        <option value="">Please select ...</option>
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
                                </select>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                                    type="button" data-bind="click: btnLoginClicked">Login</button>
                            </div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>span>select[data-bind='source: locations, value: selectedLocation']"));
   Select dropdown = new Select(element);
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-group>span>span.k-dropdown-wrap.k-state-default>span.k-input")).click();
   dropdown.selectByValue("822");
```

I get an error: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

I also tried the following:

```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".k-input")).click();

   List<WebElement> popupdd = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div>span>select[data-bind='source: locations, value: selectedLocation']>option"));

    driver.switchTo().activeElement();

    int noOptions = popupdd.size();
    System.out.println("Total options = " + noOptions);
    if (noOptions > 0) {
        for (WebElement e : popupdd) {
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("textContent"));
            if (e.getAttribute("textContent").contains(location)) {
                System.out.println("Trying to click on :  " + location);
                e.click();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("counld find the entry: " + location);
            }

        }

    }
```

It prints out correctly the option values but cannot click onthe option I want.  I get an error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Very frustrating.  Not sure how to mover forward wit this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am presently relying on the Robot class to manipulate the dropdown and want to avoid this method.

Comment: (Sorry about bad formatting. Trying to fix it). I think that's to be expected since as a human user, you also would not be able to click on a dropdown with display:none. You could either have a test page where the dropdown is visible or execute some JavaScript with selenium to show the dropdown temporarily and then hide it again. For example: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('hello world');"); }  Source: https://www.mkyong.com/selenium/how-to-execute-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a custom dropdown with its base on the standard select element as the underlying. Does clicking on the dropdown change the DOM in any way? Can you paste that HTML if that's the case?

Comment: Provide proper `HTML` code, and are you trying to select this option from dropdown `Alexandra`?

Comment: I don't see a `hidden` field/element in the shared `HTML DOM`. If it is a public URL can you share with us please? More over if you can help us formatting the HTML DOM properly (as per the actual) it would be easier for us for further analysis. Thanks

Comment: @JainishKapadia I updated the html - is more complete now.

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated the html

Comment: @tarquin See now, how different is your actual HTML DOM from the one you provided to us earlier. Anyways, Thanks for updating.

Comment: @DebanjanB yeah apologies for that it somehow lost the formatting in the copy on paste from the browser.  The answer you provided doesn't work for me.  In fact I had already tried that before but keep running into the issue in that the element I'm trying to select isn't visible.

Comment: @tarquin `The answer you provided doesn't work for me` is correct because the DropDown was not identified from the portion of the HTML DOM you provided earlier.

Comment: @DebanjanB is it possible that you can provide a solution i still havent been able to resolve this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149439/discussion-between-debanjanb-and-tarquin).

Comment: @tarquin Can you join me in the chat room?

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve this issue using the solutions provided.  I had to implement a Robot object to key to the correct dropdown which I am loathe to do.

Answer (score 0):

**1st way:** it is not the problem to click any element using the same js. As you know how to get any option the last actions remaning is to perform a click. This should work for you:

```
WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By(..selector of the element....));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

**2nd way:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'#subElement\');");
stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**3rd way:** using actions builder, advanced user actions API.

```
WebElement mnEle;
WebElement sbEle;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi @DarshitChokshi Im unfamiliar with the first method.  When I add the code,  The dropdown opens but how do i select a value from the drop down using method 1?  I try setting the argument[1].click but that doesnt work

Comment: I tried the following, the dropdown opens but the item is not selected:  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\"select[data-bind='source: locations, value: selectedLocation']>option[value='800']\");");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per your Question, to select the option `<option value="822">Alexandra</option>` you can consider trying the following piece of code:

```
WebElement select_dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-role='dropdownlist' and @data-text-field='display']"));
Select dropdownlist = new Select(select_dropdownlist);
dropdownlist.selectByVisibleText("Alexandra");
```

> OR

```
WebElement select_dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-role='dropdownlist' and @data-option-label='Please select ...']"));
Select dropdownlist = new Select(select_dropdownlist);
dropdownlist.selectByValue("822");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: This is the same issue I ran into with the methods I have tried previously: 
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated